# Executing Linux commands with double quotes

Tags: linux, command-line, ksh, quotes

So I am trying to figure out this weird behavior.

```
$ hello hello           
-ksh: hello: not found [No such file or directory]
$ "hello hello"
-ksh: hello hello: not found [No such file or directory]
$ echo hello hello
hello hello
$ `echo hello hello`
-ksh: hello: not found [No such file or directory]
$ echo \"hello hello\"
"hello hello"
$ `echo \"hello hello\"`
-ksh: "hello: not found [No such file or directory]
```

The 2nd and 6th commands are the most relevant to my question. If I run that second command `"hello hello"`, then it will evaluate that as one big argument. However, if I try to run that last command

```
`echo \"hello hello\"`
```

then it shoud have the same behavior? But it is seeing `"hello` as its own independent word. Can some explain this and how I can get that 6th command to work like the 2nd command, such that it evaluates "hello hello" as one whole statement?

(This has a more practical application, but this was the smallest example I could produce).

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I see I got a downvote, so I'll be more concrete about what problem I am running into.

```
rcli4 6379 keys AAA* | sed -e "s/.*/'&'/" | while read line; do rcli4 6379 get $line; done
```

Note that `rcli4` is just an alias for `redis-cli -p`. I keep getting a

```
(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'get' command
```

which is due to the quotation marks being parsed incorrectly. I've tried different combinations of things like adding more quotes, removing that sed statement, etc. to no avail, but I think being able to solve my original hello hello problem will give me enough insight on how to fix my specific problem.

Comment: `ksh` is not `bash`, you might need to fix your tags or your shell

Comment: Inside a quoted string, a quote is just another character.  It has no special power.

Comment: @EricRenouf Whoops! Thanks

Comment: @John1024 Yea, that's what I figured, but I am trying to figure out if there's a way to make it work with that 6th example.

Comment: @SiddSingal This might be helpful: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).  The link is written for bash but I expect that the same principles apply to ksh.

Comment: @SiddSingal If I understand the problem correctly as it is stated in the edit, the solution is to quote `$line` __inside__ the do-loop, not before it.  Thus, try: `rcli4 6379 keys AAA* | while read -r line; do rcli4 6379 get "$line"; done`

Comment: @John1024 Hmm wow okay....that worked....If you'd like, you could post that as an answer and I'll accept. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @SiddSingal Very good.  Answer added.  Also, what is the argument `AAA*`?  Is it intended to be passed _as is_ to rcli4 or does it refer to filenames that start with `AAA`?

Comment: @John1024 I am not sure how familiar you are with Redis, but redis-cli (what rcli4 is aliasing) is a cli to interact with the Redis database. I am using the "keys" command and saying I want all keys that follow the pattern AAA*, so for example AAAX or AAABBBAD

Comment: @SiddSingal Thanks for the explanation. In that case, put quotes around `AAA*`.  Otherwise, if there accidentally happens to be one or more files in the current directory whose names starts with `AAA`, the shell will replace `AAA*` with those file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a quoted string, a quote is just another character. It has no special power.

If I understand the problem correctly as it is stated in the edit, the solution is to quote `$line` **inside** the do-loop, not before it. Thus, try:

```
rcli4 6379 keys 'AAA*' | while read -r line; do rcli4 6379 get "$line"; done
```

Without the double quotes around `$line`, the shell would perform *word splitting* and *pathname expansion* on the contents of `line`.  You don't want either. Double-quotes suppresses both.

Also, we added the `-r` option to `read`.  This prevents `read` from doing backslash processing on the contents of `line`.

Lastly, we put single-quotes around the database key glob `AAA*`.  Without quotes, the shell will interpret `AAA*` as a file glob and will perform *pathname expansion* on it.  If there happen to be files in the current directory matching that glob, the results will be unexpected and unwanted.  If the bash option nullglob is set, the result will be not what you want regardless of what files are in the current directory.